# Class constructor with generic class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, class

In my application I have generic classes, and I have to construct new objects according to these generic classes. Is it possible to get a generic constructor which handle sub classes ?

I'll be more understandable with code :

I have for exemple a parent classe with two children

```kotlin
open class Fruit (
   val name: String
)

class Apple (
   name: String,
   val count: Int
) : Fruit(name) {

   constructor(name: String) : this(name, 0)

}

class Strawberry (
   name: String,
   val weight: Float
) : Fruit(name) {

   constructor(name: String) : this(name, 0f)

}
```

As you can see, my 3 classes have the same constructor (with just a name). Now I have a class, which contains a generic class of Fruit. In this class, I want to have method to create new Fruit, without care about if it's a Fruit, an Apple or a Strawberry :

```kotlin
class Farmer<GenericFruit: Fruit>(val name: String, val age: Int) {

   var cart = arrayListOf<GenericFruit>()

   fun cultivate() {

      for (_ in 1..10) {
         val fruit = cultivateFruit()
         cart.add(fruit)
      }

   }

   fun cultivateFruit() : GenericFruit {

      // Here call constructor of GenericFruit which just the parameters "name"
      val fruit = GenericFruit(name = "name of the fruit")

      return fruit
   }

}
```

I've tried to use `reified` in the method `cultivateFruit` like this :

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T: GenericFruit> cultivateFruit() : GenericFruit? {

   val constructor = T::class.constructors.find { 
      it.parameters.size == 1 && it.parameters.first().name == "name"
   }
   
   return constructor?.call("name of the fruit")
}
```

But the issue is that now I need to now the class in the method `cultivate` and Kotlin won't let me do that :

```kotlin
fun cultivate() {

   for (_ in 1..10) {
      val fruit = cultivateFruit<GenericFruit>() // Here there is an error, GenericFruit can't be called
      cart.add(fruit)
   }

}
```

The issue is that I have no reference to the generic constructor. I even not have in the `cultivateFruit` access to the class `T`. I know it is possible to achieve that on swift, I'm wondering if is it possible too with Kotlin ?

Comment: Is `GenericFruit` reified? Moreover, what does it mean to create and add a "generic fruit" to your cart?

Comment: Not entirely sure but I think this discussion talks about the same thing you are after, it might give you some insight: [Can generic parameters be reified at class level?](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/can-generic-parameters-be-reified-at-class-level/13791)

Comment: Hi, first thank you for your answers. In this example, a Farmer can cultivate only one type of Fruit. So if a Farmer<Apple> calls ```cultivate``` he can only cultivate ```Apple```

Answer (score 0):

The most honest would be to have a `static Map` of String name to the `Class<? extends Fruit>`. The name is also a class level constant, and thus should not be a constructor parameter. The constructor should be the default constructor of every child class.

```
public class Fruit ...
    public String getName() {
        return fruitClasses.get(getClass());
    }

    private static<String, Class<? extends Fruit>> fruitClasses = new HashMap<>();

    protected static register(String name, Class<? extends Fruit> fruitClass) {
        Objects.requireNull(fruitClasses.put(name, fruitClass));
    }

    public static Fruit createFruit(String name) {
        Class<? extends Fruit> type = fruitClasses.get(name);
        if (type == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "No fruit class registered for " + name);
        }
        return type.getConstructor().newInstance();
    }
}

class Apple extends Fruit {
    static { Fruit.register("Apple", Apple.class); }
```

Here every Fruit child class takes care of its own registration.

It could also be done traditionally with a **`FruitFactory`**, which seems a bit simpler for everybody. The disadvantage being that the FruitFactory either would need to import every child class, or there is no difference with the `Fruit` above.

With the new `sealed` classes in java, you define a closed domain of child classes, listing them all. Hence you could register all classes in Fruit itself.

Last but not least one may wonder whether inheritance, multiple children, is such a good idea. One can also think of capabilities, features dynamically looked up:

```
public interface JuicePressable {
    float press();
}

public interface HasSeeds {
    int seeds();
    void removeSeeds();
}

Optional<JuicePressable> jp = fruit.as(JuicePressable.class);
jp.ifPresent(fr -> ... fr.press() ...);

fruit.as(HasSeeds.class).ifPresent(fr -> fr.removeSeeds());
```

The rationale here, that if you have a categorical treatment, and would need filtering for specific actions, and the number of operational categories is open: then create a lookup of capabilities.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I'll check for the Sealed classes, maybe it can achieve what I want !

Comment: At least _sealed classes_ are state-of-the-art. Since java 17.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin answer.

Since class types can't be reified, your Farmer would need to have a property hold a reference to class type to be able to use reflection to create the fruit. You could add a companion object reified function pseudo-constructor to avoid having to explicitly pass the class type.

```
class Farmer<T: Fruit>(private val fruitClass: KClass<T>, val name: String, val age: Int) {

    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T: Fruit> Farmer(name: String, age: Int) = Farmer(T::class, name, age)
    }

    private val fruitConstructor = fruitClass.constructors.find {
        it.parameters.size == 1 && it.parameters.first().name == "name"
    } ?: error("Fruit class must have a constructor with a single argument of \"name\"")

    var cart = arrayListOf<T>()

    fun cultivate() {
        repeat(10) {
            val fruit = cultivateFruit()
            cart.add(fruit)
        }
    }

    private fun cultivateFruit(): T {
        return fruitConstructor.call("name of the fruit")
    }

}
```

Personally, I wouldn't want to rely on reflection for this. You could add a constructor parameter for the fruit's constructor. It's a little less convenient at the call site, but you would have compile-time checking so the code would be more robust.

```
class Farmer<T: Fruit>(private val fruitCreator: (String)->T, val name: String, val age: Int) {
    var cart = arrayListOf<T>()

    fun cultivate() {
        repeat(10) {
            val fruit = cultivateFruit()
            cart.add(fruit)
        }
    }

    private fun cultivateFruit(): T {
        return fruitCreator("name of the fruit")
    }

}
```

When constructing a Farmer, you can pass the constructor as the argument:

```
val strawberryFarmer = Farmer(::Strawberry, "Foo", 40)
```